# searching Freebase API for Actors info

Tags: api, actor, freebase, movies

I am trying to use the freebase API to get some data on films and actors. 
What I have is millions of Actors Imdb Ids which I would like to get info on. (such info includes: FreeBase Id, Wiki Id, Actor's Biography and Actor's Image). How can I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get you all actors with IMDB IDs in Freebase:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "key": [{
    "namespace": {
      "id": "/authority/imdb/name"
    },
    "value": null
  }]
}]
```

You can extend it with any other information that you need (but note that Freebase isn't going to have complete bios or a comprehensive set of pictures)

Comment: It doesn't contain *any* complete bios.  It only contains snippets/blurbs from the beginning of Wikipedia articles.  I don't know the number of images off the top of my head.  You'd have to count them.

Comment: how can I get the images that are the front picture of wiki's actors and not just the non relevent photos of an actor?